# GCM fail in IOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

Halo,

I created an app which use GCM for push notification, It works great if I just compile on a real ios device.

So I uploaded it on app store, but when I download the app from app store, the push notification fail... which means it can't get the notifications....

Same device, Same code, but the compile one success and app store one failed.... Does anyone know why? many many many thanks!!!!!

> [update]
>   The above case is about using ios9 or later. I found a ios8.1 iphone and try to download the app via app store, the push notification works! so now the case are:
>
> ios9+ from appstore: FAIL 
>  ios9+ from xcode: SUCCESS 
>  ios8.1 from appstore: SUCCESS 
>  ios8.1 from xcode: SUCCESS

Comment: you need to post some codes

Comment: any code i need to provide for you to figure out what is the issue?

Comment: it helps other to provide better responses

Comment: I think so too, but i have no idea why this issue occurs and also so no idea to put which part of code here for reference....